# QuickSynergy OSX server Linux client

Tags: linux, macos, synergy

How can I configure [QuickSynergy](http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/) so that my Mac can share it's keyboard and mouse with my linux computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems with this, it was almost *too* simple.

This is how *I* got it to work, other ways may be possible.

First you need to install [QuickSynergy](http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/) on both computers.

***On the client*** (The computer you want to control with the servers kbd/mouse)
Start QuickSynergy and click the **USE** tab, there you need to enter two values.

First field is the IP-address of the server.
Second is the full name of the client. (You can get it by doing nslookup on the clients IP).
[image]

***On the server***
Start QuickSynergy and click the **Share** tab.
Put in the ***Full name of the client*** (same value as in the second field above)
[image]

Then I clicked Run/Execute **without changing the tab** on the server first and then the client.